# Steam Bot - There was an error sending your trade offer. Please try again later. (26)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am configuring steam bot, that will send you an offer, when you say some number, for example, !10

The bot will send you a trade-link with 10 keys and bot will keep it...
I installed their package with node.js (steam-tradeoffer-manager)
Äfter running the code it gives an error -

```
Error: There was an error sending your trade offer.  Please try again later. (26)
    at Object.exports.makeAnError (C:\Users\tredo\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\steam-tradeoffer-manager\lib\helpers.js:17:12)
    at SteamCommunity.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tredo\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\steam-tradeoffer-manager\lib\classes\TradeOffer.js:349:12)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\tredo\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\steamcommunity\components\http.js:67:15)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\tredo\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tredo\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\request\request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Gunzip.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tredo\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at Gunzip.emit (events.js:327:22) {
  eresult: 26
}
An Error has Occured while sending offer.
```

My code looks:

```
if(isNaN(amount) || amount === undefined){
    console.log('invalid number');
}
else{
    var count = 0;
    var i = 0;
    console.log("Creating Offer, please wait!");
    //Check Players inventory for the keys, and make sure we have enough sets to supply
    var offer = manager.createOffer(_message);

    offer.getPartnerInventoryContents(440, 2, function(err, inventory, currencies){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
  var a = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < inventory.length; ++i){
                    if(inventory[i].market_hash_name === 'Reclaimed Metal' && a.length < amount){
                        console.log("Adding Item");
                        a.push(inventory[i].id);
                        offer.addTheirItem({id: inventory[i].id, appid: 440, contextid: 2});
                        console.log("Length of a "+a.length);
                        console.log(a);
                        ++count;
                    }
            }
        inventory.forEach(function(val){
            if(val.market_hash_name === 'Reclaimed Metal'){
                console.log("Adding Item");
                offer.addTheirItem({id: val.instanceid, appid: 440, contextid: 2});
                ++count;
            }
        });
        if(count < amount){
            console.log("count: "+count);
            console.log("You don't have enough keys for me to send this trade.");
        }
        else{
            offer.send(function(err, status){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log("An Error has Occured while sending offer.");
                }
                if(status == "pending"){
                    console.log("Confirming Offer!");
                }
                if(status == "sent"){
                    console.log("Offer Sent!");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I want to know whats wrong with this code..

Answer (score 0):

The code is ok, check that the asset_ID of the item you got or the asset_ID you want to give is correct, 26 means the item is not in stock

Comment: this is rather a comment than an answer IMHO